# x86 register names, addressing modes, displacement, and storage

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, addressing-mode

I have a few questions about assembly which I am learning and I am confused by.

1. What is the difference between `bx` and `bp` and `ss` and `sp`? The book says that `bx` is base register and `bp` is base pointer. Does this mean they are the same thing?
2. What is the difference with `mov ax, bx`, `mov ax, [bx]`, `mov ax, bp` and `mov ax, [bp]`?
3. What does `disp` mean in indexed addressing mode? For example `mov al, disp[bx]`? or `mov al, disp[si]`? The book does not explain meaning of `disp`.
4. Register is in CPU not RAM right?

   Please excuse my English, it is not my first langugage.

Comment: Please ask only one question per question; it's hard to tell if your questions have been answered or not once people start answering only some of your questions. Feel free to open multiple questions at the same time if you have more than one thing to ask; just keep them separate, please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oh my, these 16-bit registers became all but obsolete in 1984.  Sorry you have an old book.  Nevertheless modern processors still use these things, so your question makes sense.  I actually wrote some 16-bit assembly back in the day and oddly enough I remember it.  Yikes.

1. BX, BP, SS, and SP are just four separate registers.  BX, BP, and SP are general purpose registers (the other 16-bit GPRs are AX, CX, DX, SI, and DI) and SS is a segment register, which you don't use too often (it is implicitly used when you reference BP and SP).  A full answer to what each of these registers are far would take up far more space than a usual SO answer should.  But to answer your specific question BX and BP are two different registers, not the same one.  BP is normally used to index stack frames, and BX is normally used to index into structures or arrays.
2. `MOV AX, BX` moves the contents of BX into AX, while `MOV AX, [BX]` moves the contents of the memory location whose value is in DS:BX into AX.  That is, if BX contained the value 500, then the first instruction moves 500 into AX, while the second moves the contents of address 500 (technically 500 bytes past the beginning of segment DS) into AX.  (Note there are some subtle differences in the way MOV instructions like this are interpreted in different assemblers, such as MASM and NASM.)
3. DISP is just an abbreviation for "displacement", a number added to the value in a register to compute something like the address of a variable in a stack frame or an element in a structure.  In instructions like `MOV AX, [BX+25]` then 25 is the displacement.
4. Yes, registers are part of a CPU.

Comment: Very much thank you! Is there article I can read to clarify difference between `bx` and `bp`? Again thank you ! ^^ 4 more rep until upvote :P

Comment: Articles that may have what you need: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86#16-bit, http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/16_32_and_64_Bits#The_8086_Registers, http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/X86_Architecture#General-Purpose_Registers_.28GPR.29

Answer (score 2):

4: In the x86 architecture, registers are indeed in the CPU and *not* in RAM. Okay, I don't know of any post-1970 architectures where registers are not manifested in the CPU, but I do know of architectures (8051, for example) where registers are in the same address space as RAM is - or at least the registers are a sub-address space: instructions that access RAM can just as easily access registers, using exactly the same instruction codes, and whether the access goes off-chip to RAM or stays on-chip to the registers, depends only on the address used. In x86 though, the registers' live values are not accessible at all with memory-referencing instructions. (Unless you explicitly or implicitly save them to memory first, but we aren't talking about that here.)